# Python - self-referencing class (Vector addition using magic operators)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, magic-methods

I'm having trouble understanding how the self-reference for this class works in this code:

```
class Vector2D:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def __add__(self, other):
    return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

first = Vector2D(5, 7)
second = Vector2D(3, 9)
result = first + second
print(result.x)
print(result.y)
```

--
Just to check if I'm understanding how magic methods work, in `result = first + second`, the argument `other` refers to `second` right?

--Edit:
Thanks, I guess that clears up my confusions regarding `other`.
I still don't get how this line works though: `return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)` i.e. the class `Vector2D` being referenced inside it

Comment: "I still don't get how this line works though: `return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)`" - what exactly confuses you?

Comment: Python doesn’t use a "new" keyword to instanciate a new object from a class. The construction is simply a function call. So `Vector2D(...)` is the construction of a new instance of class `Vector2D`. Internally, the construction calls the `__new__` method and the the `__init__` method. The parameters are sent to this `__init__` method. You sould read the tutorial about classes: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain it well but, my reference tutorial hasn't made any  previous examples regarding a class being called inside it. | Did it call the class inside it just so it can create an instance in `__init__`?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE thanks. I guess my comment above is right?

Comment: In `__add__` method, your are not "calling a class Inside it", your are calling its constructor. By "calling a class Inside it" do you mean recursive call? The vocabulary you use is blur, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `other` is the right-hand-side expression result, `second` in your case.

From the [`object.__add__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__):

> For instance, to evaluate the expression `x + y`, where `x` is an instance of a class that has an `__add__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` is called.

The expression `Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)` creates a new instance of the class with new values for `x` and `y`, which here are constructed from the sum of the current instance `x` and `y` and the same attributes on the right-hand side instance.

A new instance is created because the normal semantics of `+` are to return a new instance, leaving the operands themselves untouched. Compare this to adding up two lists (`['foo', 'bar'] + ['bar', 'baz']`); there too a new list object is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is equivalent to:

```
result = first.__add__(second)
```

so:

1. `self` is `first`
2. `other` is `second`
3. `result` is the new `Vector2D`

Answer (score 1):

> the argument `other` refers to `second`, right?

Correct. You can verify that with a `print` inside `__add__`:

```
class Vector2D:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def __add__(self, other):
      print(other.x, other.y)
      return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

first = Vector2D(5, 7)
second = Vector2D(3, 9)
result = first + second

>> 3 9
```